# Having issues solving the error operand should contain 1 column

Tags: sql, max, operands

I am trying to select a name of a teacher that has the class with the most failed students.

```sql
select 
    Failed.section, max(Failed) as Failed_Class 
from 
    (select 
         e.section, count(e.grade) * 100 / (select count(*)
                                            from enrollment) as Failed
     from 
         enrollment e 
     where 
         e.grade = 'D' or e.grade = 'F'
     group by 
         e.section) as Failed;
```

This returns the section id and the percentage of failed students in that section.

```
select 
    p.name
from 
    professors p, teaches t 
where 
    p.ssn = t.ssn 
    and t.section in (select Failed.section, max(Failed) as Failed_Class 
                      from 
                          (select e.section, count(e.grade) * 100 / (select count(*) from enrollment) as Failed
                           from enrollment e 
                           where e.grade = 'D' or e.grade = 'F'
                           group by e.section) as Failed);
```

When I do a sub select statement I get the error and I do not know how to fix this?

The error I get is:

> Operand should contain 1 column

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  And *never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using

Comment: I am using mySQL

Answer (score 0):

The error is related to the fact you are using a subquery that return two column and try to match  with a in clause for one column.

Also, if you want only one teacher you could use `order by max value desc` and `limit 1`

```
select p.name
from professors p 
inner join teaches t ON p.ssn = t.ssn 
  and t.section = t.section in (
  select Failed.section
  from (
    select e.section 
    ,count(e.grade)*100/ ( select count(*)  from enrollment ) as Failed
  from enrollment e 
  where e.grade = 'D' or e.grade = 'F'
  group by e.section
  ORDER BY failed 
  limit 1 
  ) t 
);
```

Finally, you should  use explicit join syntax (not the old implicit join syntax based on where).

Comment: This causes the error 'Failed' not supported(referenced to group function)